# Process terminated when signaling a pthread waiting on "join"

Tags: c, multithreading, join, signals

I'm trying to implement a signal handler.
each pthread is created joinable, and is blocked upon all signals using sigprocmask.

The problem occurs when I send the thread a signal from another thread, using

```
pthread_kill(_threads[threadIndex], SIGHALT);
```

If the called pthread is waiting on pthread_join at the time the signal is sent, the whole proccess is terminated immidiately. However, if the thread is not waiting on join, it ignores the signal as expected. Any idea why does it happen and how to change it?

Thank you!

Comment: Is the process terminated, or is the `pthread_join` returning an error code, causing the program to finish execution?

Comment: Does anyone know about `SIGHALT`? Never seen it. Is it the same as `SIGSTOP`?

Comment: @Pavan Manjunath: Perhaps it's the german version of SIGSTOP? ;-)

Comment: What OS is this? I'm also unfamiliar with SIGHALT and I suspect the knowing that is relevant to the answer...

Comment: @Pavan Manjunath sorry for the lack of information... SIGHALT is a new signal i was supposed to create for the purpose of the exercise, using macros and threads signaling each other etc... so you can calm down - there isn't a single signal you are not familiared with. And as it turned out - the bug was somewhere else, and is fixed now. and thank you all for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the use of `sigprocmask()` in a mutithreaded environment please see this excerpt from the methods's man page:

> The use of sigprocmask() is unspecified in a multithreaded process;
>   see pthread_sigmask(3).

---

I'm a bit unsure about `SIGHALT`, but assuming it's a synonym to `SIGSTOP` the following from `pthread_kill()`'s man page might be of interest:

> Signal dispositions are process-wide: if a signal handler is
>   installed, the handler will be invoked in the thread thread, but if
>   the disposition of the signal is "stop", "continue", or "terminate",
>   this action will affect the whole process.

Comment: Even the Germans cant ignore the `SIGSTOP` signal :) But the OP quotes a situation wherein the thread ignores the signal successfully. So I guess `SIGHALT` is not `SIGSTOP`